# Restrict k so that the matrix only has three distinct real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I KNOW there are similar questions, but none of the methods are working for me. I've been trying for over an hour at this point. 
My matrix is 
A = \begin{array}{ccc}
1 &1 &0\cr
-4 &4 &1\cr
k &0 &0\cr
\end{array}

I found the characteristic polynomial to be $$-λ^3+5λ^2-8λ+k$$

I'm trying to find **_ < k < _**.

I found the first blank is 4 by guessing because finding the derivative and setting it greater than zero wasn't giving me the correct answer.

What do I do from here? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cubic polynomial has three distinct real roots iff the values it assumes at its two (real) stationary points bracket $0$. In this case, the stationary points of the characteristic polynomial $c(\lambda)$ lie at the roots of $-3\lambda^2+10\lambda-8=-(\lambda-2)(3\lambda-4)$, i.e. at $\lambda=2,\frac43$. Now $c(2)=k-4$ and $c(4/3)=k-\frac{112}{27}$, so $c(\lambda)$ has three distinct real roots, and the matrix has three distinct real eigenvalues, iff $4<k<\frac{112}{27}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!